# Can't create ExternalName type service through command line

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

On k8s you can create services either through `kubectl expose ..` command or `kubectl crate service ...` right?

So, with both of them I am having an issue that I am not sure why.

k8s allows me to do `kubectl expose deploy demo --type ExternalName`, but it doesn't allow to pass an `--external-name` flag to specify the CNAME.

```
$ kubectl expose deploy demo --type ExternalName --port 80 --external-name google.com
```

> ...
>
> unknown flag: --external-name

If I do without the `--external-name` flag.

```
$ kubectl expose deploy demo --type ExternalName --port 80
```

> The Service "demo" is invalid: spec.externalName: Required value

---

k8s also allows me to do `kubectl create service externalname demo --external-name example.com --tcp <port>:<target-port>`, but when I check the port and target port didn't go through.

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
demo               ExternalName   <none>        google.com    <none>     20m
```

I tried `--tcp=80:80`, `--tcp 80:80`, --tcp=[80:80], etc. Nothing works!

Anyone can point out what's the issue? I think it might be a bug.

I'm on GKE, with a 1.13.7 k8s version.

Answer (score 3):

A service of type ExternalName is exactly that: a local DNS CNAME record to an external domain name.

Thus exposing a deployment as ExternalName does not make sense. And since it's only a name, it does not have any ports as well.

This is all it takes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: stackoverflow
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalName: stackoverflow.com
  type: ExternalName
```

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make sense to expose a deployment. Despite the fact that if you do `kubectl expose deploy NAME -h`, ExternalName is an option. What I didn't know is that it doesn't make sense the port for ExternalName services.

Comment: yes, that really shouldn't be possible, since it does not expose the deployment in any way.